How to integrate $\int x^{-2}e^{-x}~dx$
How to integrate this indefinite integral?
$$
\int x^{-2}e^{-x}~dx
$$
I have tried the integration by parts, but I was stuck when I let $u=e^{-x},du=-e^{-x},dv=-x^{-1},v=-\ln x$. Seems that I don't know how to integrate then
$$
\int \ln xe^{-x}~dx
$$
If my method is wrong, please try another! Thanks!
This is a similar question to here. But the difference is that here it is $e^{-x}$, not $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Not sure whether the result will be the same.
But an example provided by wolfram alpha is
$$
-\frac{(e^{-x} + x~Ei(-x))}{x}
$$
But I am not sure how to get this

Check here. Let $t=-x$. Your integral turns out to be $-\int \frac{e^t}{t^2}dt$.

Also here.
